# Embeding Python3.5 script in QT application

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, qt

I am Trying to Embed a python script (python 3.5) containing a class into my QT c++ application. Before trying a GUI I was trying a simple console application. The problem is when I chose a "QT Console Application" as the new project type the code crashes but if I chose a "Plain C++ Application" (a Non-QT project Option) the program works as supposed to!

The Python Script:

```
import numpy as np
import dlib

# some other imports that also imports other modules

class myclass:

    def __init__(self, path1, path2, path3, use_Test=True):

        self.p1 = path1
        self.p2 = path2
        self.p3 = path3

        self.test = use_Test

    # some other functions

    def add(self, x, y):
        return x+y
```

this is the code i am trying in the plain C++ application:

first in the .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/python3.5
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5
```

The C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);

    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject* module = PyImport_ImportModule("myscript");
    assert(module != NULL);

    PyObject* dict = PyModule_GetDict(module);
    assert(module != NULL);
    Py_DECREF(module);

    PyObject* python_class = PyDict_GetItemString(dict, "myclass");
    assert(python_class != NULL);
    Py_DECREF(dict);

    PyObject* engine;
    if (PyCallable_Check(python_class))
    {
        PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("(sss)", "s1", "s2", "s3");
        PyObject *keywords = PyDict_New();
        PyDict_SetItemString(keywords, "tester", Py_False);

        engine = PyObject_Call(python_class, args, keywords);
        Py_DECREF(python_class);
        Py_DECREF(args);
        Py_DECREF(keywords);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot instantiate the Python class" << std::endl;
        Py_DECREF(python_class);
        return 1;
    }

    PyObject *value = PyObject_CallMethod(engine, "add", "(ii)", 2, 4);

    int result = PyLong_AsLong(value);

    cout<<"Result = "<<result<<endl;

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

This code works correctly and I get the required result from the add function. but going to QT console App, the code becomes:

PRO:

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

CONFIG += no_keywords    #Solve Python SLOT ISSUE

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += main.cpp


INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/python3.5
#INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5
```

C++

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <Python.h>


#include <QDir>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);

    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject* module = PyImport_ImportModule("myscript");
    assert(module != NULL);

    PyObject* dict = PyModule_GetDict(module);
    assert(module != NULL);
    Py_DECREF(module);

    PyObject* python_class = PyDict_GetItemString(dict, "myclass");
    assert(python_class != NULL);
    Py_DECREF(dict);

    PyObject* engine;
    if (PyCallable_Check(python_class))
    {
        PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("(sss)", "s1", "s2", "s3");
        PyObject *keywords = PyDict_New();
        PyDict_SetItemString(keywords, "tester", Py_False);

        engine = PyObject_Call(python_class, args, keywords);
        Py_DECREF(python_class);
        Py_DECREF(args);
        Py_DECREF(keywords);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot instantiate the Python class" << std::endl;
        Py_DECREF(python_class);
        return 1;
    }

    PyObject *value = PyObject_CallMethod(engine, "add", "(ii)", 2, 4);

    int result = PyLong_AsLong(value);

    cout<<"Result = "<<result<<endl;

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    Py_Finalize();

    return a.exec();

}
```

but whenever i try to run the code it crashes (the crash occures on the         PyObject* module = PyImport_ImportModule("myscript"); line)

I searched SO for a solution and an answer suggested to add the following after Py_Initialize();

```
QString qs = QDir::currentPath();
std::wstring ws = qs.toStdWString();
PySys_SetPath(ws.data());
```

This helped by not crashing the code but now all my python imports are errors (ie: ImportError: No module named 'numpy')

What am I missing in the QT APP? is there a conflict between QT and Python?

Comment: Where is the .py: in the folder of the executable or in the folder of the source code?

Comment: @eyllanesc .py script is in the executable folder

Comment: show your .py ....

Comment: @eyllanesc just added the script to the question